# Spring Security Access Control by oauth2 token

Tags: security, rest, spring-mvc, oauth-2.0

I'm working on REST web service and I have a problem. Authentication is based on oauth2. 
Suppose, registered users can store their images, which should be restricted to see only by their owners. User2 shouldn't have access to see images of User1.

For now, REST client accessing users library by request `/rest-api/users/1/photos?access_token={accessToken}`.

How should I achieve authentication which would allow to get photo library only for their owner.

Maybe by access_token, but how?

Thanks for any advice.